# Facebook bookmarks using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to open the "Facebook Bookmark" popup when an user click a button. Using [FBML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_features#FBML), I found  this code:

```
<fb:bookmark>
```

but FBML is going to be deprecated. How do I show the popup using the Facebook JavaScript library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean the 'Facebook bookmark' popup? 
Bookmarks have been automatically added when a user starts using your app since July 2010. There was an option to prompt the user to add a bookmark before that, but even if the old prompt still renders, it doesn't actually do anything anymore

Comment: i mean this one: http://min.us/moJuiqjXL   For external application there is no "auto-bookmark". So there is no more way to show it?

Comment: That picture didn't load for me but i presume it's the 'add a bookmark for {app name} dialog' from the old FBML tags - if so I don't believe there's a way to trigger it to add a bookmark for an app using only a 'Website' integration

Comment: Well, i saw the fbml code on a website. So no way to trigger it in js.. thanks.